# Service Fabric EntryPointType="Setup" different SystemGroup localizations

Tags: azure-service-fabric

According to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-dotnet-app-enable-https-endpoint#run-the-setup-script-as-a-local-administrator) I have an opportunity for run my Setup.bat with administrator privileges. I have some dev machines with different localizations and don't know what I should do with localized system groups?

Example :

```xml
<Principals>
    <Users>
      <User Name="SetupAdminUser">
        <MemberOf>
          <!--<SystemGroup Name="Administrators" />-->
          <SystemGroup Name="Администраторы" />
        </MemberOf>
      </User>
    </Users>
</Principals>
```

It works perfectly for me, but what I should do with another cases?
Can somebody push me to the right direction for digging?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I am not sure whether there is a good solution to this problem. Localization of group names is kind of a big problem and currently and as far as I know all solutions require code execution to resolve the group name by SID (Security Identifier).

Here is an existing solution in [powershell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/11/02/how-can-i-determine-the-name-of-the-local-administrators-group/).

Comment: Thanks for answer, if i understand right, we can have next pipeline:

1. We run some PS script, gets SystemGroupName and fill `SystemGroup` section in `Root/ApplicationManifest.xml`

2. We run Setup.bat and continue other steps according to tutorial

It looks little bit strange. But anyway thanks for direction!

Comment: @Yaroslav Yes, it should be something similar. Glad I helped.